# Скорость переадресации функций

Tags: c++

Что лучше в плане быстродействия: вызывать члены класса, наследованные из другого класса, или вызывать члены класса, полученные из хранящегося в классе объекта другого класса?

```
struct A {
    void foo() {
        // not inline code
        // ...
    }
};

struct B : A {

};

struct C {
    void foo() {
        return a.foo();
    }

    A a;
};


int main() {
    B b;
    C c;

    b.foo(); // ?
    c.foo(); // ?
}
```

Comment: Напишите тест, замерьте время, сообщите результаты... Скорее всего в таком примере вообще без разницы.

Comment: @VTT мне нужно в общем случае, а не в этом примере для понимания. Чем вызов методов базового класса отличается от хранения базового класса и вызова его методов, грубо говоря

Comment: @brom, для общего случая есть только стандарт C++. В нём нет ни слова про то, что Вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Получаете компилятором ассемблерный код и сморите его. В данном случае без разницы (подумайте, раз в *экземплярах* не хранится указатель на функцию (вы же его не описываете в своих данных), значит адреса функций одни и те же, они будут уточнены на этапе линковки и использованы сгенерированным кодом)

Comment: Нет никаких причин ожидать какой-то разницы в быстродействии в этих случаях.

Answer (score 1):

После того, как по коду проедется оптимизирующий компилятор, это будет все равно...

И еще запомните фразу Кнута - что корень всех бед в преждевременной оптимизации. Не надо на этом уровне начинать оптимизировать - это напоминает попытки алкоголика, пропивающего все, что можно, сэкономить на спичках :)

Вот когда ваша программа начнет не соответствовать требованиям по скорости при использовании оптимального алгоритма - вот только тогда надо брать в руки профайлер и искать *узкие места*, и оптимизировать именно их - постоянно измеряя, что получилось...

P.S. A priori в вашем конкретном случае `b.foo()` превратится в вызов `A::foo()`, а `c.foo()` при *минимальной* же оптимизации - тоже в `A::foo()`. Без оптимизации будет вызов из вызова.

Comment: потом будет уже поздно, лучше сразу спроектировать правильно. Вы уверены что нет разницы для больших `foo`, которые нельзя заинлайнить?

Comment: Вы собираетесь выполнять этот вызов 90% времени работы программы? Код ("большой", как вы пишете) будет выполняться настолько быстро, что будет сравним по времени с единственным вызовом (пусть даже со сбросом кэшей)? И еще - imho, если вы *проектируете* именно наследование/композицию не потому, что она отвечает структуре задачи, природе объектов и т.д., а исходя из вопросов эффективности - то это будет неверное решение. Иерархии классов строятся не исходя из того, каким будет получаться ассемблерный код, грубо говоря...

Answer (score 0):

При вызове нестатического метода класса в него неявно передается указатель на экземпляр этого класса `this`. Соответственно при вызове может иметь место некоторый оверхед на модификацию указателя в зависимости от организации классов. Отдельная проблема с виртуальным наследованием - в этом случае для получения указателя на экземпляр класса придется лезть внутрь текущего, то бишь лишний редирикт. Например:

```
struct C
{
   A a;
   void foo(void)
   {
      return a.foo(); // значение A * будет таким же, как и С * this
   }
};

struct C
{
   int x;
   A a;
   void foo(void)
   {
      return a.foo(); // значение A * будет вычисляться, как С * this со смещением 4 байта
   }
};

struct B : A // значение A * будет таким же, как и С * this
{};

struct B : NonEmptyFoo, A // значение A * будет вычисляться, как и С * this со смещением sizeof(NonEmptyFoo) байт
{};

struct B : virtual A // значение A * будет храниться в экземпляре класса, как и this->vptr_a
{};
```